# Share Record with profiles

Tags: community, sharing

While creating a new record for my custom object I capture (Checkboxes) if this record is to be shared with a particular profile/group or not . for example If a community user will have access or not , If an agent can see it or not etc .. and show the results to the end user as per the Profile/group while querying from database. I am afraid that this approach is incorrect because in future i may have

Answer (score 1):

You can't share to a Profile, only a User, Group, or Role (and combinations thereof). You'd have to create some sort of integration to add/remove users to Public Groups based on their profile, then you could share records with that Public Group. If you do this, you won't have to worry about filtering by using the checkboxes, which will eventually have non-selective errors, etc, and you won't have to write a full custom interface to deal with this object.